# App freezes when custom view is included in view controller

Tags: ios, uiview

When I add the `ProfileHeaderView` as a subview to a `MDCFlexibleHeaderViewController` I get the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x991fd4)
```

the error is thrown when the following method is called:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonInit()
}
```

the error is called when the `super.init()` method is called. I see no further error messages printed in the console. Any ideas of how to fix it?

FYI the code for the `ProfileHeaderView` class looks like this:

```
class ProfileHeaderView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var header: ProfileHeaderView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProfileHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(header)
    header.frame = self.bounds
    header.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]
}

/*
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

}
```

I do not subclass the `MDCFlexibleHeaderViewController`.

the error log

```
2018-10-02 22:19:14.179637-0500 builditbigger[564:444592] 5.4.1 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. 

Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2018-10-02 22:19:14.179752-0500 builditbigger[564:444592] 5.4.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.50001000 started
2018-10-02 22:19:14.184430-0500 builditbigger[564:444592] 5.4.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see url)
```

Comment: Show some more codes, like the subclass of your ```MDCFlexibleHeaderViewController``` and your ```ProfileHeaderView```. Or beter yet, a sample project.

Comment: @Glenn done ....

Comment: Can you share the code where you're creating a `ProfileHeaderView` instance and adding it as as subview? Or is it being created within a Storyboard? Also, why does `ProfileHeaderView` have an instance of itself as an outlet?

Comment: @JoelRobinson-Johnson Sorry, I forgot to request for a more detailed error log.

Comment: @Glenn I saw no error messages in log pertaining to the instantiating the view, the log is shown below

Comment: @PeteMorris, I read a tutorial on medium and that's what it told me to do (that's why the view has a reference to itself). I instantiated the view using both storyboard and in swift code. I saw the same error.